# React Style not working with template strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is this `inline style` not working?
My console logs: `The style prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.` Is it because template literals converts everything into strings?

[image]

Comment: Please include your code in text form instead of an image. `style` takes an object, not a string.

Comment: It's even worth editing your question to remove the image of text. Code is text; post text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `style` prop takes an object, so you want either `{ right: 0 }` or `{ left: 0 }`. You could solve this by using a [`computed property name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) instead of a template string:

```
const randomLeftOrRight = { [returnRandom()]: 0 };
```

Comment: Could you explain me the purpose of the square brackets? thanks!

Comment: @cyruslk Sure. You can click on the link in the answer to see what it means.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Template string, you can use like this

```
style={{ right: `${triggerNode.right+ 50}px`, left: `${triggerNode.left}px` }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const randomLeftOrRight = { [returnRandom()] : 0 };
```